# How can I trigger multiple selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Do anyone has similar experience? I would like to write a code to trigger the user when clicking the image for further action. I write the jQuery code but not successful in the trigger, code as below

```
  $( "#tab-3-list img" ).on( "click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    windows.alert( $(this).id);
  });
```

Below is the HTML code

```
<div id="tab-3-list">
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="imgspace"><img id="c01" class="coupon_list" src="/images/coupon/c01.png"></div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="imgspace"><img id="c02" class="coupon_list" src="/images/coupon/c02.png"></div></div>
    </div><!-- /grid-a -->
</div><!-- /tab-3-list -->
```

/*-------------------------------*/

I finally found the problem is if I put the div#tab-3 in main body, then the browser can trigger the click on the image. But it doesn't work if the div#tab-3 is loaded from external file using script

$(document).load("list.html");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is fine assuming you want to handle clicks on either image element, and your `.on("click")` binding will work assuming you include that code in a document ready handler or in a script block after the elements it tries to access. (And assuming you have included jQuery on your page before the code in question.)

However, you have two errors inside the handler function:

1. It should be `window.alert()`, not `windows.alert()` (no "s" in "window"). Or you can just say `alert()` without the `window`.
2. `$(this)` returns a jQuery object which doesn't have an `id` property, so `$(this).id` returns `undefined`. Just use `this.id`. If you want to call a jQuery method on the clicked image *then* you'd use `$(this)`, for example `$(this).hide()`.

So like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#tab-3-list img").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.alert(this.id);
    });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JZvvs/

Comment: Thanks, the above code works but don't know why I put it on my script didn't work. Using the alert() is the function to proof the trigger action. How do I know if the action cannot be tiggered?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "cannot be triggered". If your script isn't working, open the browser's console (F12 in Chrome and IE, ctrl-shift-K in FF) and see if any errors are displayed.

Comment: Unfortunately there was no error display but only no alert popup when click on the image. I apply this on mobile and including http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js, of course also the http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js, will that affect it?

Comment: I finally found the problem why I could not able to trigger the click on image because the div#tab-3 is under and sub page of a mobile page.

I put the code on jsfiddle.net but could not able to simulate the action http://jsfiddle.net/JwZP3/

The answer works if I put under the first page, but how I can do the same if putting under sub page?